# NoSuchMethodError after calling Future twice

Tags: mongodb, dart, dart-async

I've a simple method which fetches some data from MongoDB:

```dart
import 'package:mongo_dart/mongo_dart.dart';

Future find() {
  return _db.open().then((_) {
    return _db.collection('foo').find().toList();
  }).then((val) {
    _db.close();
    return val;
  });
}
```

It's working if I'm calling this method once. Calling it twice in a row results in a `NoSuchMethodError: method not found: 'query'`.

Could anyone explain the problem?

Here is the full stacktrace:

```
Uncaught Error: The null object does not have a method 'query'.

NoSuchMethodError: method not found: 'query'
Receiver: null
Arguments: [Instance of 'MongoQueryMessage']
Stack Trace: 
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:45)
#1      Db.queryMessage (package:mongo_dart/src/database/db.dart:174:28)
#2      Cursor.nextObject (package:mongo_dart/src/database/cursor.dart:68:29)
#3      Cursor._nextEach (package:mongo_dart/src/database/cursor.dart:102:15)
#4      Cursor.forEach (package:mongo_dart/src/database/cursor.dart:122:14)
#5      Cursor.toList (package:mongo_dart/src/database/cursor.dart:128:24)
#6      DbConnection.find.<anonymous closure> (package:schafkopfer_server/src/schafkopfer/data.dart:49:52)
#7      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:730)
#8      _RootZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:864)
#9      _Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:488)
#10     _Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:571)
#11     _Future._complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:317)
#12     Future.forEach.nextElement (dart:async/future.dart:303)
#13     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:730)
#14     _RootZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:864)
#15     _Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:488)
#16     _Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:571)
#17     _Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:331)
#18     _Future._asyncComplete.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:393)
#19     _asyncRunCallbackLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:23)
#20     _asyncRunCallback (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:32)
#21     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:128)
```

I opened a [issue for mongo_dart](https://github.com/vadimtsushko/mongo_dart/issues/53).

Comment: I assume this is a bug in mongo_dart.

Comment: OK, I'll open an issue. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you then please add the link to the issue for future reference.

Comment: I had a look at your Gist. Maybe you can't reopen a closed `Db`. `mongoTest = new MongoTest();` before the 2nd call should then solve it.

Comment: I added the link. Offtopic: The github-links in your SO-profile are broken.

Comment: You're absolutely right! Creating a new DB-Object solves the probelm. In my real application I was holding the reference to the DB in a singleton. Now I know why nothing was working...

Comment: I'd like to wait for a response from the mongo_dart developers but maybe you can add your last comment as answer. I'll accept it as soon as they give feedback.

Comment: I guess you can keep the db open. Only close it when you quit the app. If you use the connection only sporadically it's better to close it each time of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are mixing asynchronous and synchronous code and that would not work in most circumstances.

Method `find` returns Future, but you are trying call `find` second time in sync mode.
Would you call `find` second time from within `then` clause, your code would work.

```dart
main() {
  var mongoTest = new MongoTest();
  mongoTest.find().then((x) {
    print('first find $x');
    mongoTest.find().then((x) => print('second find $x'));
  });
}
```

So mongo_dart Db instance can be opened after closing, but it hardly make sense in that example.

If you are trying to do server side of web stack I would recommend you to look at existing frameworks. Redstone for example.

http://redstonedart.org/2014/07/14/managing-database-connection-with-redstondart/

Comment: Thanks, especially the redstone example helped me a lot. But I'm still not sure if I understand the problem correctly. Sure, this simplified example does not make any sense, but it's calling two times a method which is returning a future. I'd expect that they would both be put on the event-loop and executed subsequently. But seems like this is not the case because they are affecting each other.

Comment: It does not work so. You may try to pepper your code with print statements and look at actual sequence. In your example I believe sequence is something like: Open db from within first `find`, then open db from within second `find`, then do `collecion.find` in first `find` and close db in first `find`, then do `collection.find` in second `find` - which breaks.

Comment: Basically - if you want to execute two methods sequentially, place second method in `then` clause.

Comment: OK, now I see. I was not aware that two futures could share state. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Gist you linked to in the bug report the only difference between the 1st and the 2nd call is, that you use the same `db` instance. I guess the instance can't be reopened after it was closes. Creating a new instance every time before opening should solve the problem.

When the db connection is used intensively it might be better to keep it open.